# .txt filename iteration vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, iteration, filenames

I've got a little problem with regards to iterating the filename of the txt files. I've got a filename format that goes like this: `<date>-<year>_filename-<number>.txt`. The problem is that when `<number>` reaches 9, the filename stops iterating.
The filenames goes like this:

```
31-2014_filename-1
31-2014_filename-2
31-2014_filename-3
31-2014_filename-4
31-2014_filename-5
31-2014_filename-6
31-2014_filename-7
31-2014_filename-8
31-2014_filename-9
31-2014_filename-10
```

The function only detects up to 9. Anything beyond that number is ignored.
Below is the code

```
Dim lastreport As Integer = 1 
Public Sub GetLastNo(ByVal filePath As String)
    Dim lastFile As String = 1
    Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*.txt")
    For Each File As String In files
        File = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(File)
        Dim numbers As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(File, "(?<num>[\d]+)")
        For Each number In numbers
            number = CInt(number.ToString())
            If number > 0 And number < 1000 And number > lastFile Then
                lastFile = number
            End If
            lastreport = number
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no need to put `\d` inside a character class (`[…]`) because it is already a character class (unless you want to combine multiple character classes of course).

Comment: @Richard sir, so that would be `(?<num>\d+)`, am i correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I've changed it already sir, but the problem still persists.

Comment: I used a comment because that wasn't your problem, just a side issue. To address the issue I would start looking at the contents of the `MatchCollection` you are getting: I would expect three matches for each file… Personally I would look for a single regex to match all three numbers in the filename, so I know I'm working on the right number rather than relying on a condition to separate the different matches.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
(?<num>\d+(?=$))
```

This would make sure that the digits are followed by a `>` and `$`(End of line). This would make sure that it is the last set of digits.

Comment: It didn't work sir.The `$` sure did lessen up the line but it still can't detect a 10.

Comment: I am no exp. in VB but if you go to [regexhero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) and test with some sample strings eg. `<1>-<2010>_filename-<1>  
<2>-<2010>_filename-<5>  
<3>-<2010>_filename-<10>  
<4>-<2010>_filename-<101>  
<30>-<2010>_filename-<500>  
<31>-<2010>_filename-<1567>`. I found it working.

Comment: I think the `<` and `>` in the Q are just delimiting parts of the filename: those characters are not supported in filenames on Windows (and this is a VB.net question).

Comment: @Richard You are absolutely correct. Thanks for pointing out. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It would really help to see some *real* filenames, including some that fail to match (your description is not completely unambiguous: for example what is `<date>` if it does not include the year?).

But assuming files like:

```
    30May-2014_Stuff-1.txt
    30May-2014_Stuff-3.txt
    30May-2014_Stuff-5.txt
    30May-2014_Stuff-7.txt
    30May-2014_Stuff-9.txt
    30May-2014_Stuff-11.txt
```

then using the .NET regex engine (from PowerShell (PSH) here as quicker to test with):

```
(?<num>\d+)$
```

should match the final digits (`$` matches the end of the string) of the filename without extension: `BaseName` in PSH):

```
dir | foreach { if ($_.BaseName -match '(?<num>\d+)$') { $matches['num'] } }
```

gives:

```
1
11
3
5
7
9
```

So all filenames are matched, and the final number of their basenames is matched by group "num" of the regex.

I think there is something else going on in your approach: I would suggest changing to only get a single match per filename (and use [`Regex.Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx) rather than `Matches` to be consistent).

Comment: I've tried `(?<num>\d+)$` and still no good. I also tried `\d{1,}$`, `\d{1,3}`, and still it doesn't detect a double digit number at the end. However, I've noticed that when `\d{2}$` is used, it works but it can't detect a single digit number.
I'm sorry but I don't really understand your suggestion, can you please elaborate more?

Comment: @svynsaenz `\d{2}$` matches exactly two digits at the end, so it will not match other cases. Please add some real filenames to the Q (that are both successfully and unsuccessfully matched).